# Java Object returning to default values

Tags: java, sockets, serialization

I have the following code structure.

A transaction handler of type Transaction which is a field in a Client Handler class, which talks to a Server. (the client handler and the server are collocated), the client talks to the client handler via serialized object messages.

When a new transaction request comes in from the client, (comes on thread using the readObject() method of an object input stream), I then do a series of trx_handler.setFoo(trx.getFoo))). This works fine, I can handle the first request. But when a subsequent request comes in (which only starts getting executed after the first request finished due to the loop structure, I find that the trx handler has been reinitialised to its default values, the object is still there, but all the values inside are the defaut ones. What can cause this problem?

My first guess would be garbage collection, but in my Client Handler class, there is always a pointer to this trx_handler.

The code below illustrates what happens. A statement would first be of type start, so the trx_handler will be correctly initialised.  handle_statement will then be called. Subsequent statements should then be received, but at this point the trx_handler has been reinitialised to its default settings, so the access_set field is null, the session id as well, and none of the modification made to the object in hande_statement are visible

Thanks

```
  public class Handler { 

  private Statement trx_handler; 

 /* Constructor initialises trx_handler to new Statement(); */

 public ClientHandler(final Socket socket, long uid, Server server, ObjectInputStream ois) throws           IOException, Exception {
 LOGGER.info("Constructing Handler");
 this.uid = uid;
 this.server = server;
 this.socket = socket;
 this.database = server.getDB();
 this.trx_sys = database.getTransactionManager();
 create_listening(socket, ois);
 out = socket.getOutputStream();
 oos = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
 this.trx_handler = new Statement(false);
```

}

```
  private void create_incoming(final Socket socket, final ObjectInputStream stream) {
  Thread incoming = new Thread() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    ObjectInputStream ois = stream;
    InputStream in = null;
    while (true) {
      Object statement = null;

      try {

        statement = ois.readObject();
        execute_stat(statement, socket, null);
        LOGGER.info("Ready to execute next "); 
      } catch (SocketException e) {
        LOGGER.severe("Connection Closed");
        return;
      } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.severe("Connection Closed");
        return;
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        String error_message = e.getMessage();
        send_error(socket, error_message);
      }

    }
  }
};
incoming.setDaemon(true);
incoming.start();

}

 private synchronized void execute_stat(Statement trx) {
  if (trx.getTransactionState() == Consts.trx_end) {
    trx_sys.commitTransaction(trx_handler);
    return;
  } else if (trx.getTransactionState() == Consts.trx_start) {
   try {
    trx_handler.setAccessSet(trx.getAccessSet());
    trx_handler.setSession_id(trx.getSession_id());
    trx_sys.startTransaction(trx_handler);
    handle_statement(socket, trx_handler);


    /* TEST HERE THAT FIELDS IN TRX_HANDLER ARE CORRECTLY SET (INCLUDING SOME MODIFIED IN       
    handle_statement and they are correctly set */

  return;
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(ClientHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
}
try {
  LOGGER.info("Execute Trx: stat");

  /* Can't see modifications made in the start case */ 
  Statement stats = trx.getStatement();
  trx_handler.setStatement(stats);
  handle_statement(stats, socket, trx_handler);

} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();

}

return;
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with garbage collection and is likely a bug in your code. I don't think that we'll be able to guess what the bug is based on the information presented so far. Consider debugging some more and then posting more relevant code and information.

Comment: (Updated to add more detailed code)

Answer (score 0):

You need to either send a brand new object for each transaction, use `ObjectOutputStream.writeUnshared()`, or else call `ObjectOutputStream.reset()` between sends.

Comment: The problem isn't with the object I'm sending over the output stream (I'm already using reset for example) but with the field object at the Client Handler, which for some reason seems to get reinitialised to default field values in between two handle statement calls.

Comment: @user1018513 Really? have you read the Javadoc? Are you aware that if you send the same object twice with different values the second time, you will not receive the changed values? Have you *tried* any of these suggestions?

Comment: Yes, and implemented them. The Statement object that I receive in the object stream contains the correct values. It's the trx handler that gets reset.

Comment: You haven't shown how/where you instantiate class `Handler`, which is likely the problem.

Comment: So you have a bug in your code, the part you haven't posted. Speculating about garbage collection or something else magically resetting your fields is just clutching at straws.